# OpenCV library configured correctly and android app working fine for a while until an error says the library is no longer loaded

Tags: java, android, android-studio, opencv, image-processing

I have configured openCV android SDK correctly on my android studio project. This is the code I use at the start of the `MainActivity`:

```
  static
    {
        System.loadLibrary("opencv_java3");

        if(OpenCVLoader.initDebug())
            Log.d(TAG,"OpenCV configuration was a success!");
        else
            Log.d(TAG,"OpenCV configuration failed!");
    }
```

and I use the openCV methods in a class that extends `Service`.
My app, which mainly does template matching, works just fine for a while, then I get this error like the openCV library is no longer loaded (I am referring to the second one):

```
12-13 11:10:20.091 27227-27551/com.floatingbutton E/BD.Reporter: Can't getService HwBDService
12-13 11:27:54.006 30958-31089/com.floatingbutton E/art: No implementation found for long org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread_1(java.lang.String) (tried Java_org_opencv_imgcodecs_Imgcodecs_imread_11 and Java_org_opencv_imgcodecs_Imgcodecs_imread_11__Ljava_lang_String_2)
```

Why after a while the openCV library is no longer loaded?

Comment: I have developed using OpenCV library on very low end phones, but never encountered this error. Which phone model are you using for testing? Generally JVM throws `OOM` exception in case the memory of device is getting low, but haven't encountered such scenario :/

Comment: @ZdaR Sorry for the very late response, Huawei P9 Lite. I was never able to figure out the issue. I should try maybe with a high end phone?